# Cómo pasar los dos elementos de uint8_t Matriz[2] a un único uint8_t

Tags: c, matrices, conversión-de-tipos, tipos

Tengo una matriz: `uint8_t Matriz[2]` de cuyos elementos tengo que coger uno por uno, en su codificación como carácter y mostrarlos en un único uint8_t variable.

Me explico. Si tengo `Matriz[0] = 0x33` y `Matriz [1] = 0x46`, sus valores como carácter serán "3" y "F" respectivamente. Bien pues necesito una variable que finalmente muestre el valor `variable = 0x3F`.

No sé cómo se hace o si se puede hacer.
Me vendría bien la ayuda de alguien. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Sería algo así?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t matriz[2] = { 0x33, 0x46 };

    uint8_t enuno = 0;
    sscanf( (char*)&matriz, "%x", &enuno );

    printf( "Resultado: %X\n", enuno );

    return 0;
}
```

Debería funcionar pero te aparecerá un warning al compilar, debido a que la función sscanf espera que la variable **enuno** sea de tipo **unsigned int** y no **uint8_t**. Como es obvio este warning desaparecería indicando el tipo correcto para **enuno**.

Comment: Hola muy buenas!! Sí, es así, me da correcto. Además me da ese warning tal como comentas. No conocía la función sscanf. Mil gracias por tu ayuda.